# Index pdf files in AWS elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, elasticsearch, indexing

I want to index some sample pdf and then search keywords in those pdf. I have tried using elastic search on my local desktop and used fscrawler to index the pdf. But my main aim is to create a web application where I can upload pdf and then enter a search term. I have created elasticsearch cluster on AWS but cannot figure out how to index pdf in AWS. Can I store the pdf on S3 and then index them?

Comment: mostly pdf file is not possible to index directly. you need to first read all text from pdf and need to index as ES cannot read pdf file directly. You can use third party plugin if you any exist.

Comment: https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler

Comment: Yes, I get that I will need to index pdf first. But how do I go about the same on AWS. I need to store the pdf on S3 then index it and then load to elasticsearch. I know this is possible, but I am not getting the appropriate resources to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting S3 as a FS implementation is something I'd love to support in the future. See https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/issues/263

That being said, I believe that [Workplace Search](https://www.elastic.co/workplace-search) will support it at some point.